# Removing zero length hidden files

Tags: shell-script

Write a Bash script that takes a file name and a directory name as command line arguments and removes the
file if it is found under the given directory and is a zero length file, a .swp file (maybe hidden) or a .tmp file (maybe hidden).

Can someone provide this code please?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: There is not such thing as a `.tmp` file, or `.swp` file. File extensions were a thing in the 1980 with DOS and CPM. Today Microsoft's file-explorer still uses the end of the file-name, to determine which program to run, when a file is clicked on. Some other file-explorers also do this. There is also no hidden files on Unix. However there are files that are not normally shown, files that start with a `.` You can use `find` to find files with what ever name pattern you want, and that is also empty.

Comment: also see `test` (`man test`).

Answer (score 2):

This lists file recursively in directory «directory-name», that are regular files, have a name starting with a dot (hidden), and are empty

`find «directory-name» -type f -name ".*" -empty`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a echo-version (instead of `rm`, easier to test) of what I think makes sense.

The idea is to split it up in two parts. First, test for empty and remove conditionally. Then, `rm` with option `-f` the 4 variations. Here it is 4 echoes on two lines, nicely formatted to show the *whitespace* in the filename.

```
f="$1"

[ -e "$f" ] && [ ! -s "$f" ] && echo "$f" || echo '(nosuch)'

echo ---"$f".swp--- ---."$f".swp---
echo ---"$f".tmp--- ---."$f".tmp---
```

Here the output, the second time after un-emptying the file.

```
]# . delswp.sh 'f f'

f f
---f f.swp--- ---.f f.swp---
---f f.tmp--- ---.f f.tmp---

]# echo " " >>'f f'
]# . delswp.sh 'f f'

(nosuch)
---f f.swp--- ---.f f.swp---
---f f.tmp--- ---.f f.tmp---
```

With remove the second part could be just:

`rm -f "$f".swp ."$f".swp "$f".tmp ."$f".tmp`